Building local python-package with conda failed
I try to create a local python-package with conda (miniconda) without any uploads and without using git. Just for private purposes.
There must be a general issue preventing success.
Everything is pretty simple
My filestructure:
my_root_folder/
── mbutils/
├── _init_.py
├── epoch_utils.py
├── misc_utils.py
├── meta.yaml
└── setup.py
My _init_.py:
from epoch_utils import EpochUtils
from misc_utils import MiscUtils

__all__ = ["EpochUtils", "MiscUtils"]

My Python files are like that:
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import time
import pytz

class EpochUtils:

    tz_utc = pytz.timezone("UTC")
    tz_local = pytz.timezone("Europe/Berlin")

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_epoch_from_localtime(self, st: str) -> int:
        # macht aus einem ISO-String (tz=localtime) eine Epoch-Time (in diesem Fall eine local-Time)
        return int(self.get_ts_from_string(st).timestamp())

    # ... and so on...

My conda-recipe:
package:
    name: mbutils
    version: 1.18

source:
    path: .

build:
    noarch: False
    number: 1
    script: "{{ PYTHON }} -m pip install . -vv"

requirements:
    host:
         - python >=3.10,<3.13
         - pip
         - setuptools

    run:
        - python >=3.10,<3.13

about:
    author: MB
    summary: tools
    description: utility-package

My setup.py File:
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = "mbutils",
    version = "1.18",
    packages = find_packages(),
    install_requires = [],
    author = "Your Name",
    author_email = "your.email@example.com",
    description = "A utility package",
)

I installed Python 3.12, conda-build (24.9.0), pip, setuptools etc.
I startet creating Package with conda build mbutils from "my_root_folder".
At the end, I get the appropriate package "mbutils-1.18-py312_1.tar.bz2" in the conda-bld directory, without any error-messages:

Successfully built mbutils
Installing collected packages: mbutils
Successfully installed mbutils-1.18
Removed build tracker: '....\pip-build-tracker-75_5e2a5'
Resource usage statistics from building mbutils:
Process count: 2
CPU time: Sys=0:00:00.2, User=0:00:00.1
Memory: 53.2M
Disk usage: 19.6K
Time elapsed: 0:00:04.1
Packaging mbutils
Packaging mbutils-1.18-py312_1
number of files: 7
Fixing permissions
INFO :: Time taken to mark (prefix)
0 replacements in 0 files was 0.01 seconds

I installed the package with conda install --use-local mbutils.
I checked the successful installation with conda list mbutils.
So far so good.
But:
When I try to import the package with python, python can not find it:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mbutils'

I tried a lot of variants, tips and hints, asked AI-Tools (Open-AI, Gemini), but at the end, I can not use my package.
Has anybody an idea, how to get my package work?
Thanks to all in advance,
Micha.
